# How to set kafka schema registry cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have set up zookeeper and kafka broker cluster. I want to setup multiple schema registry cluster for fail over.
Zookeeper cluster having 3 node
kafka broker cluster having 3 node.

Could you please mention details steps how to set multiple schema registry?

I am using confluent 5.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schema Registry is designed to work as a distributed service using single master architecture, so at any given time there will be only one master and rest of the nodes refer back to it. You can refer the schema-registry arch [here](https://docs.confluent.io/5.0.0/schema-registry/docs/index.html)

You can choose 3 nodes schema-registry cluster (you can run on the same nodes along with zookeeper/Kafka), As you are using confluent 5.0, you can use the confluent CLI,

```
confluent start schema-registry
```

Update the schema-registry.properties,

```
 #zookeeper urls
 kafkastore.connection.url=zookeeper-1:2181,zookeeper-2:2181,...
 #make every node eligible to become master for failover 
 master.eligibility=true
```

On the consumer and producer side, pass the list of schema-registry urls in the Consumer.props & Produce.props

```
props.put("schema.registry.url","http://schemaregistry-1:8081,http://schemaregistry-2:8081,http://schemaregistry-3:8081")
```

*By default schema-registry port will be 8081.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want set up schema registry cluster on single server. I want want to setup 3 instance with different port. Does schema registry run on different port other than 8081?

Comment: Yes you can do that by modifying the schema-registry.properties 
    listeners = listener_name://host_name:port

Comment: Schema Registry should ideally use Kafka rather than Zookeeper for leader election